# Get the Drop coordinates (x / y) relative to the DropTarget in Vaadin 23 via build-in drag and drop feature

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using the `Drag Source` and `Drag Target` features from https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/create-ui/dnd (Vaadin 23).

I want to realize a moving operation on a map. This means I got points on a map (as custom Vaadin components) and ...

- when dragging them the source position should be hidden (this could be done via `point.addDragStartListener(...);` as far as I can see)
- when dropping them I need to know the drop position relative to the map as x/y coordinates (e.g. clientX and clientY).

As result, the component should be moved from the dragging start position to the drop position. It's parent div has the style attribute `position: relative;` and the component itself has an absolute position with top and left coordinates in px, e.g.: `position: absolute; top: 183px; left: 254px;`. With the drop event I have to update the `top` and `left` values in the css styling and therefore I need the coordinates of the drop position.

I can't see a suitable method in `dropTarget.addDropListener(...);` to get the coordinates. Do you have any hint / code samples for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
dropTarget.getElement().addEventListener("drop", this::onDrop)
            .addEventData("event.offsetX")
            .addEventData("event.offsetY");
```

And an apropriate method onDrop:

```
private void onDrop(DomEvent event) {
    
    JsonObject eventData = event.getEventData();
    double x = eventData.getNumber("event.offsetX");
    double y = eventData.getNumber("event.offsetY");
    
    [do some stuff...]

}
```